# Overflow for astype(int) with big number

Tags: python, pandas, overflow, rounding

I have the following number in python:

```
import pandas
x = pandas.Series(1508770848527.423339843750000)
```

When I'm using `x.apply(np.floor)` I'm getting 1508770848527.0 but when I'm applying `x.astype(int)` I'm getting -2147483648.

How can I prevent this overflow? I would like to have the number as an integer.

Comment: `x.astype(np.int64)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to `int64`:

```
print (x.astype('int64'))
0    1508770848527
dtype: int64
```

Or like commented [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263061/overflow-for-astypeint-with-big-number/47263093#comment81476847_47263061):

```
print (x.astype(np.int64))
0    1508770848527
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is one of these options better than the other? Is there a difference?